# Passing mysql_query to JSON file does not work

Tags: php, mysql, json, while-loop

I have a small code that should convert a query to my mysql database into a json file, but it does not return anything.

I have seen this example in many places but it does not work for me

Of course I checked before the query contains rows

I appreciate the help

```
<?php
    if (!$enlace = mysql_connect('X.X.X.X', 'xxxx', 'xxxx') or !mysql_select_db('xxxx', $enlace)) {
        echo 'No pudo conectarse a mysql';
        exit;
    }


    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `Tabla`'; 
    $resultado = mysql_query($sql, $enlace);

    $json = array();
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
              $json[]=$row;
        }



    echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

Comment: mysql_* is depreciated , use mysqli_* instead of

Comment: I have been asked to be with mysql_query :(

Comment: What contains ``$json`` before the ``json_encode()`` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for not getting anything is because you are overwriting the array variable,
also note that you need to use `mysqli` since `mysql_` is deprecated.
Change this line:

```
$resultado = mysql_query($sql, $enlace);

    $json = array();
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
              $json=$row;
        }
```

to:

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($sql, $enlace);

    $json = array();
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
              $json[]=$row;
        }
```

Comment: Sorry for my silly mistake, but it still does not work in spite of making the mentioned change :(

Comment: then make sure your table has data

Comment: If, as I mentioned, I have looked at the number of rows that $ result contains, and indeed if it contains rows

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all use mysqli instead of mysql it is deprecated since PHP 5.5.0.
And then add the row to the array instead of overwriting it.

```
$json[] = $row;
```

for test add this line in the loop

```
$json = [];
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
      $json[] = $row;
      print_r($row);
}
```

If you get no output the query is not giving you any results

Comment: Sorry for my silly mistake, but it still does not work in spite of making the mentioned change :(

Answer (score 0):

You may try converting to array to be sure.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
          $json[]=(array)$row;
}
```

and yes simple debugging is important just use var_dump() to identify the issue

```
var_dump(['socket:', $resultado]); $i=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
      $json[]=(array)$row;
      var_dump([$i++, $row]);
}
exit();
```

And of course you should not use deprecated functions but i assume this is a learning environment or just an old working system